# ADO.NET Reader Always Returns False with Wcf Service

Tags: c#, wcf, ado.net

I am trying to retrieve a single column record in Angular JS Application. I am entering correct text into input filed but the problem is data reader object always returns false .

Here is the Interface.

[OperationContract]

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
UriTemplate = "/GetCustomers/{Account_Holder_Last_Name}")]
string GetCustomers(string Account_Holder_Last_Name);
```

Here is the Implementation .

```
 public string GetCustomers(string Account_Holder_Last_Name)
        {

            List<object> customers = new List<object>();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Current_Account_Holder_Details WHERE Account_Holder_Last_Name =@Account_Holder_Last_Name";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_Holder_Last_Name", Account_Holder_Last_Name);
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (sdr.HasRows)**//Always returns false on this line**
                        {
                            while (sdr.Read())
                            {

                                customers.Add(new
                                {
                                    Tittle = sdr["Tittle"],
                                    Account_Holder_First_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_First_Name"],
                                    Account_Holder_Last_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_Last_Name"],
                                    Account_Holder_DOB = sdr["Account_Holder_DOB"],
                                    Account_Holder_House_No = sdr["Account_Holder_House_No"],
                                    Account_Holder_Street_Name = sdr["Account_Holder_Street_Name"],
                                    Account_Holder_Post_Code = sdr["Account_Holder_Post_Code"],

                                    Account_Holder_Occupation = sdr["Account_Holder_Occupation"],
                                    Account_Number = sdr["Account_Number"]



                                });
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }

                return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(customers));
            }

        }
```

Here is the Angular js Code ..

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
            $scope.IsVisible = false;
            $scope.Search = function () {
                var post = $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCustomers/{Account_Holder_Last_Name}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { Account_Holder_Last_Name: $scope.Account_Holder_Last_Name },

                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                });

                post.success(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.Customers = eval(data.d);
                    $scope.IsVisible = true;
                });

                post.error(function (data, status) {
                    $window.alert(data.Message);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        Name:
        <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Holder_Last_Name" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Search(Account_Holder_Last_Name)" />
        <hr />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ng-show="IsVisible">
            <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                <th> Tittle</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th> Last Name</th>
                <th>  DOB </th>
                <th> House No</th>
                <th> Street Name</th>
                <th>Post Code</th>
                <th> Occupation</th>
                <th>Account Number</th>


            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{m.Tittle}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_First_Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Last_Name}}</td>

                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_DOB}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_House_No}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Street_Name}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Post_Code}}</td>

                    <td>{{m.Account_Holder_Occupation}}</td>
                    <td>{{m.Account_Number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Sql script .

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Current_Account_Holder_Details](
    [Account_Holder_Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Tittle] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Account_Holder_First_Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Account_Holder_Last_Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Account_Holder_DOB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Account_Holder_House_No] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Account_Holder_Street_Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Account_Holder_Post_Code] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Account_Holder_Occupation] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Account_Number] [int] NULL,
)
```

Here is the database record .
[image]

Here is the screen shot in VS2015.
[image]
Here is the result when i run the application .
[image]

Comment: What happens if you remove .HasRows? Are you using Sql LocalDB ? Maybe you are not pointing to where you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCustomers/{Account_Holder_Last_Name}",
dataType: 'json',
data: { Account_Holder_Last_Name: $scope.Account_Holder_Last_Name },
```

should perhaps be:

```
url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/GetCustomers/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Holder_Last_Name),
dataType: 'json'
```

This will ensure that `Account_Holder_Last_Name` is correctly set server-side.

Comment: I really thanks you for your valuable time . Thanks very much for your time @mjwills